# Kafka messages deletion not happening

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a small integration test with local kafka cluster and its compaction policy.
I'm raising a kafka container with the following props:

`KAFKA_LOG_CLEANER_DELETE_RETENTION_MS: 10000 KAFKA_LOG_CLEANER_MAX_COMPACTION_LAG_MS: 2000 KAFKA_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 5000`

also, I'm dynamically creating topics with the following specs:
`return TopicBuilder .name("topic_1") .partitions(1) .replicas(1) .compact() .config(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_MS_CONFIG, "2000") .config(TopicConfig.DELETE_RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "1000") .config(TopicConfig.MIN_CLEANABLE_DIRTY_RATIO_CONFIG, "0.1") .config(TopicConfig.MAX_COMPACTION_LAG_MS_CONFIG, "4000") .build();`

Then I'm running another container, which is publishing a key/value message, waiting for 5sec, sending tombstone with the same key and then awaits until both messages dissapear from the topic.
The awaiting is done like this:
I'm creating a dummy consumer, which subscribes to both topics and just checks if topics have any records:
`consumer.subscribe(List.of(topic1, topic2)); ConsumerRecords<String, ?> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000)); Assertions.assertEquals(0, records.count()); log.info("Test executed successfully");`
I am aware that kafka segmenting is separating the messages to clean and dirty log portions, but I want to push the broker to delete them as fast as possible, so my assertions to pass.
Any ideas how I can improve this or what is settled wrong?

[example with 11mins non deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csP1o.png)

I've tried setting delete policy on cluster level / topic level / also pushing dummy data to invoke the broker to move the tombstones to the dirty portion.

still not working